# whats wrong with my prepared statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, prepared-statement

The SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT rownum rid ,condata.*
    FROM (
        SELECT max(ODP_CTT.NUM_CTT_ID) conid  ,ODP_CTT.VC2_BUS_CTT_ID AS ecpid  ,ODP_CTT.vc2_title AS title   ,ODP_CTT.vc2_briefly AS description   ,EC_ECP_INFO.vc2_price AS opri   ,ec_ecp_info.vc2_discount AS npri   ,max(ODP_CTT.vc2_dft_icon) AS iurl   ,to_char(ec_ecp_info.dat_update, 'yyyymmddhhmiss') AS upt   
        FROM ODP_CTT ,ec_ecp_info
        where odp_ctt.num_status = 3
        and (
            lower(vc2_title) LIKE lower('%?%')
            or lower(ODP_CTT.vc2_briefly) LIKE lower('%?%')
        )
        AND ec_ecp_info.vc2_ecp_id = odp_ctt.VC2_BUS_CTT_ID
        GROUP BY ODP_CTT.VC2_BUS_CTT_ID   ,ODP_CTT.vc2_title ,ODP_CTT.vc2_briefly   ,EC_ECP_INFO.vc2_price ,ec_ecp_info.vc2_discount  ,to_char(ec_ecp_info.dat_update, 'yyyymmddhhmiss')
    ) condata
    order by  to_number (upt) desc
)
```

and  I set:

```
stmt.setString(1, keyword_f);
stmt.setString(2, keyword_f);
```

and I get :

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lower(vc2_title) LIKE lower('%?%')
or lower(ODP_CTT.vc2_briefly) LIKE lower('%?%')
```

I don't think you can put the `?` inside a string. You probably need to do this:

```
lower(vc2_title) LIKE lower(?)
or lower(ODP_CTT.vc2_briefly) LIKE lower(?)
```

Then in the Java:

```
stmt.setString(1, "%" + keyword_f + "%");
stmt.setString(2, "%" + keyword_f + "%");
```

Comment: @user452187 I updated my answer. It's substantially the same, just without the `**`